# Add a TensorBoard metric from my PettingZoo environment

Tags: reinforcement-learning, tensorboard, stable-baselines, pettingzoo, multi-agent-reinforcement-learning

I'm using Tensorboard to see the progress of the PettingZoo environment that my agents are playing. I can see the reward go up with time, which is good, but I'd like to add other metrics that are specific to my environment. i.e. I'd like TensorBoard to show me more charts with my metrics and how they improve over time.

The only way I could figure out how to do that was by inserting [a few lines](https://gist.github.com/cool-RR/8dc91f5e092a7751cf10a9776f04ee1f) into the `learn` method of `OnPolicyAlgorithm` that's part of SB3. This works and I got the charts I wanted:

[image]

(The two bottom charts are the ones I added.)

But obviously editing library code isn't a good practice. I should make the modifications in my own code, not in the libraries. **Is there currently a more elegant way to add a metric from my PettingZoo environment into TensorBoard?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a callback to add your own logs. See the below [example](https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/tensorboard.html). In this case the call back is called every step. There are [other](https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/callbacks.html#custom-callback) callbacks that you case use depending on your use case.

```
import numpy as np

from stable_baselines3 import SAC
from stable_baselines3.common.callbacks import BaseCallback

model = SAC("MlpPolicy", "Pendulum-v1", tensorboard_log="/tmp/sac/", verbose=1)


class TensorboardCallback(BaseCallback):
    """
    Custom callback for plotting additional values in tensorboard.
    """

    def __init__(self, verbose=0):
        super(TensorboardCallback, self).__init__(verbose)

    def _on_step(self) -> bool:
        # Log scalar value (here a random variable)
        value = np.random.random()
        self.logger.record('random_value', value)
        return True


model.learn(50000, callback=TensorboardCallback())
```